# Error setting up Appium driver in Swift 2

Tags: swift, selenium, appium, swift2

Where `driver = SERemoteWebDriver(serverAddress: "127.0.0.1", port: 4723, desiredCapabilities: capabilities, requiredCapabilities: nil, error: &error)` worked in Swift 1 it is now giving an error:

`cannot find an initializer for type 'SERemoteWebDriver' that accepts an argument list of type '(serverAddress: String, port: Int, desiredCapabilities: SECapabilities, requiredCapabilities: nil, error: inout NSError?)'`

Sorry - still getting my head around Swift 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift 2 brings new error handling functionality: the updated signature for this method no longer includes the final parameter `error`, instead the initializer now `throws` and should be wrapped in a `do...catch` (and called with `try`) -> see documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10)

an example might be:

```
do {
  let driver = try SERemoteWebDriver(serverAddress: "127.0.0.1", port: 4723, desiredCapabilities: capabilities, requiredCapabilities: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
  print("Error: \(error.domain)")
}
```